# Citation aliases in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex, citing, natbib

I am using Beamer with the Frankfurt style. I have some citations in the presentation and a list of references at the end.

First I tried using the standard \cite and \bibliography with \bibliographystyle{plain}:

The Bibliography appears beautifully formatted in Beamer style with little icons for the type of document. But the citation in the text appears as [1], even though [1] does not appear in the Bibliography listing.

I wanted to create an alias for the citation using free text. I tried using natbib:

```
\defcitealias{jon90}{Paper~I}
\citetalias{jon90}
```

This gives me the citation that I want, but then I lose the beautiful formatting of the Bibliography at the end (it reverts to standard natbib style).

How can I get natbib-style citation aliasing to work alongside Beamer Frankfurt bibliography formatting?

**MWEB**

test.bib:

```
@misc{mybibitem,
  title        = {The Presentation},
  author       = {Anon Y Mous},
  howpublished = {\url{http://somewebsite}}
}
```

test.tex, to get nicely formatted references but with [1] as the citation label:
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Frankfurt}

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My Content}{Source: \cite{mybibitem}}
Some content
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{References}{}
\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Alternate test.tex, to get custom citation label but ugly formatted references:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\defcitealias{mybibitem}{My Custom Label}
\begin{frame}{My Content}{Source: \citetalias{mybibitem}}
Some content
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{References}{}
\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: MWEB added as requested.

Comment: First of the `plain` style is not compatible with `natbib` so it cannot provide author-year if that is what you are after. Switching to `plainnat` and deliting `aux` and `bbl` files + recompile, then it works as expected.

Comment: I am not trying to use author-year, I want to provide my own custom label alias. Changing to plainnat does not give the Beamer-style formatting.

Comment: How should `Paper~I` appear in the bibliography?

Comment: It's literal text

Answer (score 3):

Finally I made a solution which is a bit of a hack but was sufficient for this presentation.

I am not using natbib as it loses the Beamer reference formatting. The following formats the references how I want them:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}{}
\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\end{frame}
```

Then I redefined the \bibitem command and created a new \citealias command to give the user-defined reference labels and hyperlink cross-referencing within the document:

```
\let\oldbibitem=\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\label{mybib#2}\oldbibitem[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand\citealias[2]{\hyperlink{mybib#1}{#2}\phantom{\cite{#1}}}
```

References are cited like this:

```
\begin{frame}{My Content}{Source: \citealias{mybibitem}{My Custom Label}}
```

The hacky part is that I am hiding the original citation label using \phantom, which adds a blank space to the end of the citation text. But as I always have citations at the end of a line that was OK for my use case.